# In which order are workflow items processed?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have a number of workflow items on cases in SuiteCRM.

How can I determine the order in which these items are processed?  In my situation, I am setting the priority of the case based on the values of some integer fields.  However, these integer fields must first be populated based on the values of some dropdowns.

How can I make sure they are populated in the correct order?  I can't see an order of execution with the workflow items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow simply pulls the workflow items to run using `get_full_list` which will just give the items in whatever order the database returns them (probably by id).

The alternatives are to add a new hidden flag field to the case to signify that the values have been set then check this in the workflow conditions.

Allowing setting a priority for a workflow would be a good addition however and I've added this on the SuiteCRM GitHub: https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/issues/280

Comment: Thanks.  I created the workflow items in the order I wanted them to run and they *appear* to run in the right order.  Setting a priority order would be handy so thanks for adding that to github.